# Convert MS Access TRANSFORM/PIVOT query to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, pivot

I need to transform an access query to sql server query but I am getting an error, can someone point me to the error cause?

Here is the MS Access query:

```
TRANSFORM Avg([X Avg Sub Group]) AS [AvgOfX Avg Sub Group]
SELECT Day, Process, 
       PARTNO_VAL0, CTQNO_VAL0, 
       ctq_description, MACHINE_VAL0, 
       usl, lsl, 
       Avg([X Avg Sub Group]) AS [Total Of X Avg Sub Group]
FROM [Capability Data with Shift]
WHERE (((Process)="BBB WELDING"))
GROUP BY Day, Process, PARTNO_VAL0, CTQNO_VAL0, ctq_description, MACHINE_VAL0, usl, lsl
PIVOT SHIFT_VAL0;
```

Here is what I have done:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(avg([X Avg Sub Group]))
FROM [Capability Data with Shift]
WHERE (((Process)='BBB WELDING'))
GROUP BY Day, Process, PARTNO_VAL0, CTQNO_VAL0, ctq_description, MACHINE_VAL0, usl, lsl, SHIFT_VAL0
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
,1,1,'');

SET @query =  ' SELECT Day, Process, PARTNO_VAL0, CTQNO_VAL0, ctq_description, MACHINE_VAL0, usl, lsl, [Total Of X Avg Sub Group], ' + @cols + '
FROM 
(
SELECT Day, Process, PARTNO_VAL0, CTQNO_VAL0, ctq_description, MACHINE_VAL0, 
usl, lsl, SHIFT_VAL0, Avg([X Avg Sub Group]) AS [Total Of X Avg Sub Group]
FROM [Capability Data with Shift]
WHERE (((Process)=''BBB WELDING''))
GROUP BY Day, Process, PARTNO_VAL0, CTQNO_VAL0, ctq_description, MACHINE_VAL0, usl, lsl, SHIFT_VAL0
) t
PIVOT
(
  avg([Total Of X Avg Sub Group])
  FOR SHIFT_VAL0 IN( ' + @cols + ') 
) p ';
Execute(@query);
```

This is the result I am getting when I execute the query in SQL Server:

> (1 row(s) affected)
>
> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 1, Line 17 Error converting data type
>   nvarchar to int.
>
> Msg 473, Level 16, State 1, Line 17 The incorrect value "0.000642857"
>   is supplied in the PIVOT operator.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Invalid column name 'Total Of X Avg
>   Sub Group'.

Comment: Try printing your dynamic sql string before executing it. This should be always be done anyway so you actually know what you are running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have such universal stored procedure for pivoting

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[msrTransformAsAccessDo]
    @TRANSFORM_Function nvarchar(max),
    @TRANSFORM_Field nvarchar(max),
    @SQL_SELECT nvarchar(max),
    @SQL_FROM_WHERE nvarchar(max),
    @SQL_GROUPBY_HAVING_ORDERBY nvarchar(max),
    @PIVOTBY nvarchar(max) 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @DynSQL nvarchar(max)

    SET @DynSQL = N' SELECT DISTINCT ' + @PIVOTBY + ' as key_value into ##pivoting ' + @SQL_FROM_WHERE + ' ORDER BY ' + @PIVOTBY

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ##pivoting
    EXEC (@DynSQL)

    DECLARE @Values nvarchar(max) = N''
    DECLARE @tmpStr nvarchar(max)
    DECLARE @rsk CURSOR         

    SET @rsk = CURSOR SCROLL
        FOR 
            select key_value from ##pivoting
    OPEN @rsk         
        FETCH NEXT FROM @rsk INTO @tmpStr
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
            BEGIN
                SET @Values = @Values + ', ' + @TRANSFORM_Function + '(Case When convert(nvarchar,' + @PIVOTBY + ')=convert(nvarchar,''' + @tmpStr + ''') Then ' + @TRANSFORM_Field + ' Else Null End) AS [' + @tmpStr + '] '
                FETCH NEXT FROM @rsk INTO @tmpStr
            END
    CLOSE @rsk

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ##pivoting

    SET @DynSQL = @SQL_SELECT + ' ' + @Values + ' ' + @SQL_FROM_WHERE + ' ' + @SQL_GROUPBY_HAVING_ORDERBY

    EXEC (@DynSQL)
END
GO
```

And call for your case:

```
EXECUTE msrTransformAsAccessDo 
   'Avg', 
   '[X Avg Sub Group]', 
   'SELECT Day, Process, PARTNO_VAL0, CTQNO_VAL0, ctq_description, MACHINE_VAL0, usl, lsl, Avg([X Avg Sub Group]) AS [Total Of X Avg Sub Group] ', 
   'FROM [Capability Data with Shift] WHERE (((Process)=''BBB WELDING'')) ', 
   'GROUP BY Day, Process, PARTNO_VAL0, CTQNO_VAL0, ctq_description, MACHINE_VAL0, usl, lsl ', 
   'SHIFT_VAL0'
```

Comment: Thank you this worked for me... changed the DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ##pivoting because I am using al older SQL Server version...

Answer (score 1):

A multi-user version without cursor:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].msrTransformAsAccessDo
    @TRANSFORM_Function nvarchar(MAX),
    @TRANSFORM_Field nvarchar(MAX),
    @SQL_SELECT nvarchar(MAX),
    @SQL_FROM_WHERE nvarchar(MAX),
    @SQL_GROUPBY_HAVING_ORDERBY nvarchar(MAX),
    @PIVOTBY nvarchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @Values nvarchar(MAX) = N''
    DECLARE @tmpStr nvarchar(MAX)
    DECLARE @RowCnt INT
    DECLARE @id int = 1
    DECLARE @DynSQL nvarchar(MAX) = N'INSERT INTO #pivoting SELECT DISTINCT ' + @PIVOTBY + ' as key_value ' + @SQL_FROM_WHERE + ' ORDER BY ' + @PIVOTBY
    EXEC (@DynSQL)
    SELECT @RowCnt = COUNT(*) FROM #pivoting;
    --replace cursor
    WHILE @id <= @RowCnt
    BEGIN
        SELECT @tmpStr = key_value from #pivoting where id = @id
        SET @Values
                    = @Values + ', ' + @TRANSFORM_Function + '(Case When convert(nvarchar,' + @PIVOTBY
                    + ')=convert(nvarchar,''' + @tmpStr + ''') Then ' + @TRANSFORM_Field + ' Else Null End) AS [' + @tmpStr
                    + '] '
        SET @id += 1
    END
    SET @DynSQL = @SQL_SELECT + ' ' + @Values + ' ' + @SQL_FROM_WHERE + ' ' + @SQL_GROUPBY_HAVING_ORDERBY
    EXEC (@DynSQL)
END
```

Also need to create temp table before you call the procedure (global temp is not session specific):

```
BEGIN
    --create temp table to ensure each user session has their own version of the pivot
    CREATE TABLE #pivoting (id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL, key_value NVARCHAR(max))
    EXECUTE [dbo].msrTransformAsAccessDo
   'Avg', 
   '[X Avg Sub Group]', 
   'SELECT Day, Process, PARTNO_VAL0, CTQNO_VAL0, ctq_description, MACHINE_VAL0, usl, lsl, Avg([X Avg Sub Group]) AS [Total Of X Avg Sub Group] ', 
   'FROM [Capability Data with Shift] WHERE (((Process)=''BBB WELDING'')) ', 
   'GROUP BY Day, Process, PARTNO_VAL0, CTQNO_VAL0, ctq_description, MACHINE_VAL0, usl, lsl ', 
   'SHIFT_VAL0'
    DROP TABLE #pivoting
END;
```